# BlueStacks with Android 7 works fine but Android Pie never starts

Tags: bluestacks

With the newer release of bluestack I got to know Android support for Pie. But when I when I tried to create a new instance for `pie` support it show me this issue `Pie(64) version is not supported on this operating system`. Please provide me solution, It will be very helpful

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check few things here.

1. If BlueStacks 5 Nougat 32-bit or Nougat 64-bit is already installed on your PC, then you can create a Pie 64-bit (Beta) instance on it using the Multi-Instance Manager.
2. Windows 11 will not support of 64-bit Pie.
3. Your bluestacks version should be 5.2.100 or above to use this feature.

For more details just check [official doc](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406032772877-How-to-use-Android-Pie-64-bit-Beta-on-BlueStacks-5-#%E2%80%9C2%E2%80%9D)

[image]

Comment: My system is `x64` that is why i cannot download `Nougat 32-bit`

Comment: You don't have to download  `Nougat 32-bit` it is default present

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question actually. The doc linked says nothing about solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Hypervisor disabling** has a lot more to do with than just the "**Hyper V**" in the '**turn windows features on or off**'. Make sure to tick off at least a couple of more tick boxes detailed here in the [official support page](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/articles/4409852112781?locale=en-us#%E2%80%9C2%E2%80%9D). These were the "**Virtual machine platform**" and "**Windows hypervisor platform**" for me. Once the Hypervisor support is completely removed, Pie 64 is able to be installed, instantiated, and run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by disabling Hyper V using an .exe file, which you can download from the official Bluestacks website at the [link](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360055244412-How-to-disable-Hyper-V-on-Windows-to-run-BlueStacks-5)

Comment: Windows 11 supports of 64-bit Pie.